# mariadb master to master replication auto increment settings

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, auto-increment, database-replication

I have just made a maria db master to master replication and after few days, I realized following the tutorial now the auto increment is by 2 instead of 1 as normal.

I am wondering, would it be save to set it back to 1? or it's the best to leave it at 2 instead of same id bumped to each other while creating rows.  That seeing id always increment by 2 would consider a healthy db too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auto_increment_increment` > 1 is needed for any multi-master setup.  Without it (and `auto_increment_offset`), `AUTO_INCREMENT` values will collide and cause *serious* trouble.

`AUTO_INCREMENT` *only* guarantees uniqueness, nothing else.  Do not depend on incr by 1, being sequential, no gaps, or anything else.  If you have a need for some other requirement, let's discuss *that* in a new Question.

Comment: got what you mean. don't really have requirements but this is my first time doing this.  I just want to make sure that I am not doing it really wrong that I have no way turning back in the future.  Just wondering, I know I have other nodes `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2` which is the reason for 2 increments.  I am fine with it as long as it's not a trouble but if I only change the first node `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0` would that cause collide easily too?

Comment: @Dora - I think you must use `auto_increment_increment` when you are writing to multiple masters.  I don't think the `lock_mode` plays a role in this -- multiple masters do _not_ coordinate with each other; replication is _asynchronous_.

Comment: I was looking at the wrong setting, at first I thought it's the `lock_mode` is actually the offset setting I should be looking at

Comment: I do have another question though.  I do know about the gap but I wonder if it's a normal behavior with the gap though?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102516/mariadb-is-this-kind-of-increment-offset-reaction-consider-normal

Comment: You should simply expect to be missing id=2 (or other number**s**) in some situations.