# mariadb, is this kind of increment offset reaction consider normal?

Tags: database, mariadb, auto-increment, database-replication

I posted a similar question a bit earlier but I was a bit confused because of the settings already set and by reading this http://mariadb.org/auto-increments-in-galera/ I totally understand and corrected the settings but from what I read the output of the auto increment id will be like

both nodes are increment of 2

node 1 with offset 1
`1,3,5,7`

node 2 with offset 2
`2,4,6,8`

but when I create new rows...this happens

create with node 1, node 1, node 2 would give me
`1,3,4`
it wouldn't give me `2`

create with node 1, node 2, node 1, node 2 would give me
`1,2,3,4`

I am just wondering if this kind of reaction is considered as normal or there is something I am missing that I should correct?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Galera is designed for both nearly-synchronous replication *and* speed.  There are tradeoffs.  You have uncovered one of them.  I suspect a *similar* "gap" can be found in the old dual-Master replication.

Live with it!

`AUTO_INCREMENT` values are guaranteed to be unique.  Period.  Full stop.  There are a lot of other attributes that you might *like*, but you cannot assume them.

Another doc:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/tips-on-converting-to-galera/#auto_increment